# How to get rid of extra area in plotly js

Tags: javascript, plotly, bootstrap-5, plotly.js

I have following code:
(Which display simple Plotly chart from the documentation https://plotly.com/javascript/gauge-charts/

```
  function updateSpeedChart(motor1, motor2) {
  var data1 = [
    {
      domain: { x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1] },
      value: motor1,
      title: { text: "Motor1" },
      type: "indicator",
      mode: "gauge+number",
      gauge: {
        axis: { range: [null, 100] },
        steps: [
          { range: [0, 60], color: "lightgreen"},
          { range: [60, 80], color: "orange"},
          { range: [80, 100], color: "red"},
        ],
        }
      }
  ];
  var data2 = [
    {
      domain: { x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1] },
      value: motor2,
      title: { text: "Motor2" },
      type: "indicator",
      mode: "gauge+number",
      gauge: {
        axis: { range: [null, 100] },
        steps: [
          { range: [0, 60], color: "lightgreen"},
          { range: [60, 80], color: "orange"},
          { range: [80, 100], color: "red"},
        ],
        }
      }
  ];

  const config = {
    displayModeBar: false,
    responsive: true,
  };
  
  var layout = {
    paper_bgcolor: "#aaa",
    margin: { r:30, l:30, t:0, b:0},
  };

  Plotly.newPlot('speedChartDivMotor1', data1, layout, config);
  Plotly.newPlot('speedChartDivMotor2', data2, layout, config);
}

updateSpeedChart(38, 25);
```

This Plotly chart is inserted into the Boostrap grid system and cards.

```
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.24.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
      <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">Speed</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
            <div id="speedChartDivMotor1"></div>
            <div id="speedChartDivMotor2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

It creates following picture:

[image]

Please help me to get rid of the extra gray area. Bottom and top. But still have the design responsive.

Comment: I don't think there's a plotly option combination that will prevent the chart to grow in height if you let the container's height unset.  So it becomes a Bootstrap/css problem to set the height. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/3k0ovfy1/) a possible variant based on [css aspect-ratio](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio)